# If a is a $\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$ generator, if $k$ is not a multiple of $p-1$, $a ^ k \not\equiv 1\pmod p$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $a$ is a $\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$ generator, if $k$ is not a multiple of $p-1$, $a ^ k \not\equiv 1\pmod p$.

I don't understand why.

What does "$a$ is a $\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$ generator" mean?

Please tell me.

Comment: Use the definition of generator or think what could be the order of a ?

Comment: @Chinmaya mishra G={a^n｜n∈Z/pZ}...What should I do next?

Comment: think when can be the power of a be 1?

Comment: Oh it's p-1. But...what does " is a ℤ/ℤ generator" mean?

Comment: It means that a generates the whole group ℤ/ℤ or any element of ℤ/ℤ can be represented as power of a .

Comment: Is it necessary for ≢1(mod) ? I mean, without  " is a ℤ/ℤ generator" , ≢1(mod). Is that right?

Comment: By the Theorem in the linked dupe: since $\,{\rm ord}(a) = p-1\,$ then $\, a^k\equiv 1\iff p-1\mid k.\ $ This is a basic result that should be mastered as early as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ has order $p$, $\operatorname{ord}(a)=p$. But this means that, in particular, that $a^k\neq1$ if $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,p-2\}.$

Comment: ∈{1,2,…,−2}?

Comment: Right. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ is a generator, then $a,a^2,\ldots,a^{p-1}$ are all different. Because if there were two of them equal, in that sequence there would be fewer than $p-1$ different elements.

We know by little Fermat's Theorem that $a^{p-1}=1$.

So take $k$ s.t. $a^k\neq 1$. Now use Euclidean division $k/(p-1)$: $k=q(p-1)+r$. Then
$$a^k=a^{q(p-1)+r}=(a^{p-1})^q\cdot a^r=1^q\cdot a^r=a^r$$

Since $k$ is not a multiple of $q-1$, $r\neq 0$ and $r<p-1$. So $a^k\neq 1$.

Comment: I understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If you're question is "Let $a$ be a generator of $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$, if $k$ is not a multiple of $p-1$, then $a^k \not \equiv 1$ (mod $p$)".

Then this is the same as asking "Let $a$ be a generator of $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$, if $a^k \equiv 1$ (mod $p$), then $k$ is a multiple of $p-1$."